# Matrix Calculation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering, modeling, mathematics

I would like to Calculate Q. The transpose of U matrix is a 2x5 matrix and U is a 5x2 matrix. Therefore, I was expecting a 5*5 Matrix, which wasn't the case. Can someone please help me to solve Q [image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your numbers are right.  You are just confused about matrix multiplication.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication (or any linear algebra textbook):

> For matrix multiplication, the number of columns in the first matrix must be equal to the number of rows in the second matrix. The result matrix has the number of *rows* of the first and the number of *columns* of the second matrix.

(emphasis mine)

If you really want a 5x5 matrix, you need to compute $U  U^T$

Comment: Thank you for you answer